# How to Exclude Hours, Minutes and Seconds in AngularJS Date?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, date

I'm receiving data from `JSON` file via `$http.get` request. In my JSON file this is the format I receive:

```
"date": "2016-10-24 15:14:53"
```

I want to format it to be like this: `October 10 2016` (without `hh-mm-ss`)

My code:

```
<body data-ng-app="myApp">

<div data-ng-controller="alfaCtrl1" class="blogwrapper" id="blogFirst">
<span>{{date}}</span><span></span>
</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('jsonfile.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.date = data.posts[0].date;
    });
});
</script>
</body>
```

This question is different from the one proposed as "duplicate", since it expands the process to Angular way of formatting date.

Comment: Downvoter, please explain?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a JavaScript date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Comment: use moment.js.  [Here is a plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/pxxo5LZsdZQk14PBWf9O?p=preview).

Comment: Duplicate question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var formateDate = new Date(data.posts[0].date)
$scope.date = $filter('date')(formateDate, 'longDate');
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting an error saying: $filter is not defined.

Comment: Add the $filter in the controller as a dependency

Comment: It outputs now: 2016-10-24 15:14:53... just like with my example.

Comment: new Date() -> creates a new Javascript date Object. And the angular $filter changes the format of the date. You can read here more about the date $filter: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Answer (score 3):

** This is not relevant to your question but, might be prove helpful for others in future.

### Here are all doc with example you can utilize from it in case of you want to apply it in vie.

The date filter allows us to format a date based upon a requested format style. The date formatter provides us several built-in options. If no date format is passed, then it defaults to showing mediumDate (as you can see below).

Here are the built-in localizable formats:

```
{{ today | date:'medium' }} <!-- Aug 09, 2013 12:09:02 PM -->
{{ today | date:'short' }} <!-- 8/9/13 12:09 PM -->
{{ today | date:'fullDate' }} <!-- Thursday, August 09, 2013 -->
{{ today | date:'longDate' }} <!-- August 09, 2013 -->
{{ today | date:'mediumDate' }} <!-- Aug 09, 2013 -->
{{ today | date:'shortDate' }} <!-- 8/9/13 -->
{{ today | date:'mediumTime' }} <!-- 12:09:02 PM -->
{{ today | date:'shortTime' }} <!-- 12:09 PM -->
```

The date formatter also enables us to customize your date format to our own liking. We can combine and chain together these format options to create one single date format, as well:

**Year Formatting**

```
Four-digit year: {{ today | date:'yyyy' }} <!-- 2013 -->
Two-digit padded year: {{ today | date:'yy' }} <!-- 13 -->
One-digit year: {{ today | date:'y' }} <!-- 2013 -->
```

**Month Formatting**

```
Month in year: {{ today | date:'MMMM' }} <!-- August -->
Short month in year: {{ today | date:'MMM' }} <!-- Aug -->
Padded month in year: {{ today | date:'MM' }} <!-- 08 -->
Month in year: {{ today | date:'M' }} <!-- 8 -->
```

**Day Formatting**

```
Padded day in month: {{ today | date:'dd' }} <!-- 09 -->
Day in month: {{ today | date:'d' }} <!-- 9 -->
Day in week: {{ today | date:'EEEE' }} <!-- Thursday -->
Short day in week: {{ today | date:'EEE' }} <!-- Thu -->
```

Hour Formatting

```
Padded hour in day: {{ today | date:'HH' }} <!-- 00 -->
Hour in day: {{ today | date:'H' }} <!-- 0 -->
Padded hour in am/pm: {{ today | date:'hh' }} <!-- 12 -->
Hour in am/pm: {{ today | date:'h' }} <!-- 12 -->
```

**Minute Formatting**

```
Padded minute in hour: {{ today | date:'mm' }} <!-- 09 -->
Minute in hour: {{ today | date:'m' }} <!-- 9 -->
```

**Second Formatting**

```
Padded second in minute: {{ today | date:'ss' }} <!-- 02 -->
Second in minute: {{ today | date:'s' }} <!-- 2 -->
Padded millisecond in second: {{ today | date:'.sss' }} <!-- .995 -->
```

**String Formatting**

```
am/pm character: {{ today | date:'a' }} <!-- AM -->
4-digit representation of time zone offset: {{ today | date:'Z' }} <!-- -0700 -->
```

Some examples of custom date formatting:

```
{{ today | date:'MMM d, y' }} <!-- Aug 09, 2013 -->
{{ today | date:'EEEE, d, M' }} <!-- Thursday, 9, 8 -->
{{ today | date:'hh:mm:ss.sss' }} <!-- 12:09:02.995 -->
```